# Let $\eta$ be $4 X 1$ vector and $C$ a $4 X 4$ symmetric matrix. Is it possible to simplify the following expression? (expression too big for title!)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let:
$\eta = \begin{bmatrix} \eta_1 \\ \eta_2 \\ \eta_3 \\ \eta_4 \end{bmatrix}$ and its derivative in respect to time: $\dot{\eta} = \frac{d\eta}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix} \dot{\eta_1} \\ \dot{\eta_2} \\ \dot{\eta_3} \\ \dot{\eta_4} \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $C$ be a $4 \times 4$ **symmetric** matrix whose elements are all functions of $\eta_1$, $\eta_2$, $\eta_3$ and $\eta_4$.

I have the following system of 4 equations (one for each element):

$\begin{cases} 
a_1 = \dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_1}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
a_2 = \dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_2}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
a_3 = \dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_3}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
a_4 = \dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_4}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
\end{cases}$

I need to rewrite this system in Matrix form, so I defined $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ a_4 \end{bmatrix} $ and rewrote the equation as:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_1}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_2}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_3}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_4}\right) \dot{\eta} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

And managed to show it is equivalent to:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_1}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_2}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_3}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_4}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix} \dot{\eta}$

It is possible to rewrite the expression $\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_1}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_2}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_3}\right) \\
\dot{\eta}^T \left(\cfrac{\partial C}{\partial \eta_4}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix}$ in a more simplified/compact way, defining maybe some kind of tensor operation or matrix derivative operator?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Define
the scalar
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \dot\eta^T C\dot\eta \\
 &= (\dot\eta\otimes\dot\eta)^T \v(C) \\
 &= v^T c \\&= c^Tv \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product and the vec operation stacks the columns of $C$ to create one long column vector $c$.

The vector in question is the gradient of this scalar, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A &= \p{\phi}{\eta} &= \left(\p{c}{\eta}\right)^Tv \\
A_k &= \p{\phi}{\eta_k}
 &= \left(\p{c}{\eta_k}\right)^Tv
 \,\;=\; \dot\eta^T\left(\p{C}{\eta_k}\right)\dot\eta \\\\
}$$
**NB:**   This assumes that $\{\eta,\dot\eta\}$ are independent variables, such as position and velocity.

Comment: Oh that's very interesting, thanks a lot! It would be very convenient for me though if in the Matrix form I had $\dot{\eta}$  explicitly on the right, with the form $A = D \dot{\eta}$, instead of having the Kronecker product on the right. Do you think it is possible to find a matrix $D$ for this?

Comment: The problem is that the gradient $\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial \eta}\right)$ is a third-order tensor and doesn't mix well with matrix notation. Your original expression is the best that can be done.  If you are willing to switch to index notation, then the result is simple and unambiguous $$D_{kj} = \dot\eta_i\left(\frac{\partial C_{ij}}{\partial\eta_k}\right)$$